# Appropriate type for coordinate axis?

Tags: c#, constructor, unity-game-engine

I'm having problem declaring the constructor type for the variable `axis`. I tried float but obviously it's not working.

```
private void SortDistAxis(List<Transform> targetsList, var axis)
{
    targetsList.Sort(
    delegate (Transform t1, Transform t2) 
    {
            return selectedTarget.Find("localChild").transform.InverseTransformPoint(t2.position).axis.CompareTo 
                (selectedTarget.Find("localChild").transform.InverseTransformPoint(t1.position).axis);
    });
}
```

I could resort to this method, but it feels dirty. Any alternative?

```
private void SortDistAxis(List<Transform> targetsList, string axis)
{
    if (axis == "x")
    {
        targetsList.Sort(
        delegate (Transform t1, Transform t2) 
        {
                return selectedTarget.Find("localChild").transform.InverseTransformPoint(t2.position).x.CompareTo 
                    (selectedTarget.Find("localChild").transform.InverseTransformPoint(t1.position).x);
        });
    }
    if (axis == "y")
    {
        targetsList.Sort(
        delegate (Transform t1, Transform t2) 
        {
                return selectedTarget.Find("localChild").transform.InverseTransformPoint(t2.position).y.CompareTo 
                    (selectedTarget.Find("localChild").transform.InverseTransformPoint(t1.position).y);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can consider using a delegate to get the axis you want?

```
private void SortDistAxis(List<Transform> targetsList, Func<PointF, float> axisFunc)
{
    targetsList.Sort(
    delegate (Transform t1, Transform t2) 
    {
         return axisFunc(selectedTarget.Find("localChild").transform.InverseTransformPoint(t2.position)).CompareTo 
               (axisFunc(selectedTarget.Find("localChild").transform.InverseTransformPoint(t1.position)));
    });
}
```

Usage would be:

```
SortDistAxis(targetsList, p => p.x);
SortDistAxis(targetsList, p => p.y);
```

I'm assuming the type returned by `InverseTransformPoint` is `PointF`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this (run-time code modification) directly in C#, but there's by-way;
you can address `Vector3[index]` instead of `Vector3.x, Vector3.y, Vector3.z`:

```
enum Axis {
  X = 0,
  Y = 1,
  Z = 2
}

private void SortDistAxis(List<Transform> targetsList, Axis axis) {
  targetsList.Sort(
  delegate (Transform t1, Transform t2) {
    return selectedTarget.Find("localChild").transform.InverseTransformPoint(t2.position)[axis].CompareTo 
                              (selectedTarget.Find("localChild").transform.InverseTransformPoint(t1.position)[axis]);
  });
}
```

Comment: +1 - nice solution since `Vector3` supports both indexed access and individual properties. Probably will be faster than more generic answer by Zong Zheng Li (+1 too).

Answer (score 1):

What you're suggesting can't be done in C#. You should create an enum and pass that as your axis argument. Your updated code would look something like this

```
enum Axis
{
    X,
    Y
}

private void SortDistAxis(List<Transform> targetsList, Axis axis)
{
    if(axis == Axis.X)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```